# How to prove that if ${_}$ is bounded in $(C^0[0,1],‖⋅‖_∞)$, then ${_}$ is bounded in $(^0[0,1],‖⋅‖_∞)$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, complete-spaces, sequence-of-function, cauchy-problem

Given the following differential equation
$u''(t)={f}_{k}(x)$  with initial conditions $u(0)=u'(0)=0$; where ${f}_{k}(x)$∈($C^{0}[0,1],\| \cdot \|_{∞}$).
How can I prove that if {${f}_{k}$} is a bounded sequence in ($C^{0}[0,1],\| \cdot \|_{∞}$), then {${u}_{k}$} is bounded in $(C^{0}[0,1],\| \cdot \|_{∞})$?
I only know that ($C^{0}[0,1],\| \cdot \|_{∞}$) is a complete metric space..
Can someone help me please?

Comment: Is it $x$ or $t$?

Comment: @Shaqinho the exercise says x, but I think that's t

Comment: Ok, because $x$ would make no sense here. Are you able to find a concrete formula for $u$?

Comment: @Shaqinho I know the formula for the derivative u' (given by the fondaumental theorem of integration) but not for u..

Comment: Nice! Just apply the fundamenta theorem again...

Comment: @Shaqinho yes but then how can I prove that uk are limited?

Answer (score 1):

By the fundamental theorem of calculus we have that
$$
u_k(t) = \int^t_0 \int_0^s f_k(x)~\mathrm{d}x~ \mathrm{d}s.
$$
Hence (note that $0 \leq s \leq 1$):
$$
\lVert u_k \rVert_{\infty} \leq \sup_{t \in [0, 1]}\int^t_0 \int^s_0
\lVert f_k \rVert_{\infty} ~\mathrm{d}x ~\mathrm{d}s \leq \lVert f_k \rVert_{\infty} \leq \lVert f_k \rVert_{\infty}$$
This means that $\lVert u_k \rVert_{\infty}$ has at least the same bound as $\lVert f_k \rVert_{\infty}$.

Comment: Thank you @Shaqinho

Comment: Then if i know that ${f}_{k}\rightarrow{f}_{∞}$ uniformly, how can I prove that ${u}_{k}\rightarrow{u}_{∞}$, where ${u}_{∞}$ is the solution of the problem with ${f}_{∞}$?

Comment: The same way: $\displaystyle \lVert u_k - u_{\infty} \rVert_{\infty} = \left \lVert \int^t_0 \int^s_0 f_k - f_{\infty} ~\mathrm{d}x~\mathrm{d}s \right \rVert_{\infty} \leq \lVert f_k - f_{\infty} \rVert_{\infty} \overset{k \rightarrow \infty}{\longrightarrow} 0$